# What jQuery event/method can I use to bind on a dynamic button before click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bind, jquery-events

I'm trying to attach a jQuery plugin to a dynamically generated button. I've tried the following with no success:

```
$('.myButton').live('click', function() {
    $(this).file().choose(function(e, input) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

I guess this doesn't work as the plugin needs binding *before* click.

So I tried...

```
$('.myButton').load(function() { ... });
```

and (getting desperate now)...

```
$('.myButton').live('load', function() { ... });
```

What method can I use to bind a newly generated button before the user clicks on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either bind it when you generate it, e.g. if it's generated by [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), then it would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  //options...
  success: function(data) {
    //do stuff
    $(".myButton", data).file().choose(...);
  }
});
```

The important part there is the `, data`, we're giving the [selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) a [context](http://api.jquery.com/context/) to search it, so it's only finding buttons that were loaded in the response.  This same technique applies to the success methods on [other `$.ajax()` shorthand versions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) as well.

---

If that's not an option, then there's a not-as-performant-route available.  You can use [the `.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) which actively looks for and acts upon new elements, whatever the source.  Your code would look like this in that case:

```
$(".myButton").livequery(function() {
  $(this).file().choose(...);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the code:

```
    $('.myButton').live('click', function() {
        $(this).file().choose(function(e, input) {
        // ...
        });
    });
```

AFTER you've dynamically added your button (so basically add it in the routine that adds the dynamic button).

jim

Comment: that's a good point. Do you think actually I should be doing that with all my dynamic content instead of using live()?

Comment: fearofawhackplanet - i think nick's use of .livequery should sort out most of the edge cases that you are encountering and where it's not appropriate, then do it inside the dynamic routine.